# SQL - Multiple rows with ID but I would like to join all info in one column

Tags: sql

I have the Table Example:

| id | RowA | RowB | RowC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VA1 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | VB1 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | VA2 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | VB2 | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | VA3 |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | VB3 |

And I want to get this as a result:

| id | RowA | RowB | RowC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VA1 | VA2 | VA3 |
| 2 | VB1 | VB2 | VB3 |

I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id,
    b.RowA,
    c.RowB,
    d.RowC,
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT ID
     FROM Example) a
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         id,
         RowA
     FROM Example
     WHERE RowA IS NOT NULL) b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         id,
         RowB,
     FROM Example
     WHERE RowB IS NOT NULL) c ON a.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         id,
         RowC
     FROM FLOWFILE
     WHERE RowC IS NOT NULL) d ON a.id = d.id
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks guys

Comment: The id is not unique? You might want to look at how to create a basic SQL table because either your example is wrong or your table is laid out very strange.

Comment: I assume you mistyped the sample data: `1 | NULL | NULL | VB3` should probably be `2 | NULL | NULL | VB3`

Comment: Yes, Jon you assume well. I already edit the post.

Erik this is an example and "id" column is not unique.

Comment: Tim has a reasonable answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT id, MAX(RowA) AS RowA, MAX(RowB) AS RowB, MAX(RowC) AS RowC
FROM Example
GROUP BY id;
```

Here we are aggregating by `id` and simply taking the maximum value for each column, per `id`.  It is a property of the `MAX` function that it ignores `NULL` values.  As each `id` only has a single non `NULL` value, the above approach works.